# Typeorm migration @CreateDateColumn() timestamp not increment

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, typeorm

Using **Typeform** and **postgrasql** for DB

I have this **Post** entity with an auto-generated **createAt** column using @CreateDateColumn() from Typeorm. I was trying to add 5 entries of fake posts to DB using Typeorm migration.

`npx typeorm migration:create -n FakePosts`

The issue is that all 5 posts end up having the same **createAt** timestamp "2023-05-30T02:40:32.318Z"? Is this how it's supposed to be? What was I doing wrong here? How can I config Typeform to get an incremented **createAt** timestamp on a single migration?

**/entity/Post.ts**

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Post extends BaseEntity {
  @Field()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Field()
  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  title!: string;
}
```

**/migration/1685412921219-FakePosts.ts**

```
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from "typeorm";

export class FakePosts1685414339712 implements MigrationInterface {
  public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query(`
    insert into post (title, text, "authorId") values ('American Madness', 'In sagittis dui vel nisl. Duis ac nibh. Fusce lacus purus, aliquet at, feugiat non, pretium quis, lectus.

    Suspendisse potenti. In eleifend quam a odio. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
    
    Maecenas ut massa quis augue luctus tincidunt. Nulla mollis molestie lorem. Quisque ut erat.', 1);
    insert into post (title, text, "authorId") values ('It''s Pat', 'Etiam vel augue. Vestibulum rutrum rutrum neque. Aenean auctor gravida sem.', 1);
    insert into post (title, text, "authorId") values ('Wicked Little Things', 'Pellentesque at nulla. Suspendisse potenti. Cras in purus eu magna vulputate luctus.
    
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus vestibulum sagittis sapien. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
    
    Etiam vel augue. Vestibulum rutrum rutrum neque. Aenean auctor gravida sem.', 1);
    insert into post (title, text, "authorId") values ('There''s Only One Sun', 'Proin interdum mauris non ligula pellentesque ultrices. Phasellus id sapien in sapien iaculis congue. Vivamus metus arcu, adipiscing molestie, hendrerit at, vulputate vitae, nisl.
    
    Aenean lectus. Pellentesque eget nunc. Donec quis orci eget orci vehicula condimentum.', 1);
    insert into post (title, text, "authorId") values ('Fairly Odd Movie: Grow Up, Timmy Turner!, A', 'In congue. Etiam justo. Etiam pretium iaculis justo.
    
    In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam faucibus cursus urna. Ut tellus.
    
    Nulla ut erat id mauris vulputate elementum. Nullam varius. Nulla facilisi.', 1);
    
    `);
  }

  public async down(_: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {}
}
```

**query all posts**

```
{
  "data": {
    "posts": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "createdAt": "2023-05-30T02:40:32.318Z",
        "title": "American Madness"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "createdAt": "2023-05-30T02:40:32.318Z",
        "title": "It's Pat"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "createdAt": "2023-05-30T02:40:32.318Z",
        "title": "Wicked Little Things"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "createdAt": "2023-05-30T02:40:32.318Z",
        "title": "There's Only One Sun"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "createdAt": "2023-05-30T02:40:32.318Z",
        "title": "Fairly Odd Movie: Grow Up, Timmy Turner!, A"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This youtube tutorial video from Ben Awad explained the issue:
https://youtu.be/I6ypD7qv3Z8?list=RDCMUC-8QAzbLcRglXeN_MY9blyw&t=27131